# How to use the Z3 Solver to solve a natural deduction problem

Tags: z3, smt, sat, sat-solvers

I've installed the Z3 Solver from Github using Visual Studio and the commands: python scripts/mk_make.py, cd build, and nmake. I'm a little lost on how to go about solving an equation using this Solver. I have a natural deduction problem with many assumptions and a final implication that needs to be proved.

I see python files in the build\python folder but I have no idea how to run them or build my own file for my problem.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You might want to read through https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html and https://smt.st/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf. Latter has tons of examples.

Comment: @alias I understand the syntax, I'm just trying to figure out how to use Visual Studio after building Z3, or if I should just use something like Pycharm and import Z3.

Comment: The easiest is just use your favorite text-editor to put your program in, and then call z3/python from the command line. That's the only mode I ever used it and it works just fine.